# How to select just two elements of all matched elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to select just two `td.clsname` of each `tr`. I want to select these:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>     //   <---- this
        <td class="clsname">...</td>     //   <---- this
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>    //   <---- this
        <td class="clsname">...</td>    //   <---- this
        <td class="clsname">...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="clsname">...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do that?

```
$('table tr').find('td.clsname').text();
```

^ This finds all of them, how can I limit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`$('table tr').find('td.clsname:first-child:nth-child(2)').text();`

Comment: Give me a minute ... I would mark it as my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`$('table tr').find('td.clsname')` returns an array. If you want to select specific elements, you could use [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/).

For instance, `$('table tr').find('td.clsname').slice(index1, index2).text()`.

Answer (score 1):

this will give you elements of individual tr

```
var tr = $("tr");
    for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++)
    {
        console.log($(tr[i]).find(".clsname:lt(2)"));
    }
```

and this will give array of all first two child with the classname within tr

```
console.log($("table tr").find(".clsname:lt(2)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
 $('table tr').each( function(){
  alert($(this).find('td.clsname:nth-child(1)').text());
  alert($(this).find('td.clsname:nth-child(2)').text());
 });
```

Hope this will help you.